# Will evolving the Pokémon Day 2017 festive Pikachu give me a festive Raichu?

Tags: pokemon-go

It was announced on the official [Pokémon Go website](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/pokemonday2017) that:

> Did you know February 27 is Pokémon Day? We’ve teamed up with our friends at The Pokémon Company International for their annual celebration of all things Pokémon, and we have a special treat for you this Pokémon Day! From February 26 at 1:00 P.M. PST to March 6 at 1:00 P.M. PST, special Pikachu appearing all over the world will be celebrating Pokémon Day by wearing festive party hats. These special Pikachu will keep their party hats forever, but they can only be found during this limited-time celebration, so make sure to keep an eye out for them as you explore!

The special Pikachu looks like the following:

[image: special Pikachu]

If I evolve my special Pikachu, do I also get a special Raichu with a hat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this website](http://www.imore.com/pokemon-day-event) it appears that you can:

> You can't catch a Party Hat Raichu the same way you catch holiday Pikachu, but you can evolve it from a Party Hat Pikachu. That's as long as you have 50 Pikachu Candy you're willing to spend on it.

[image: Images of pikachu turning into Raichu with hat]

<sub>[Image Source](http://www.imore.com/pokemon-day-event)</sub>

As I commented, they did something similar for Christmas, which when you evolved that Pikachu, you got a Raichu with a Christmas Hat.  It makes sense for them to keep it consistent between the events.  However for the Christmas Event, you were able to capture a Raichu with a hat as well.

Comment: Actually, you could catch Santachu directly... so not entirely consistent.

Comment: @Joe well when I meant consistent, I just meant the evolving part.

Comment: Sure, but they were only 50% consistent, which doesn't seem very consistent to me... might be worth at least mentioning that in the answer.